# Bloquear mais de uma chamada HTTP

Tags: javascript

eu faço uma chamada via API para um serviço de uma aplicação, que me retorna algumas informações do meu produto. Está funcionando OK, porém, sempre que eu clico no botão, a tabela é alimentada, ou é feito o apend de todo conteúdo. Eu quero que a chamada seja feita apenas uma única vez ou que mesmo que eu clique no botão várias vezes, não seja feito o append caso já tenha as informações.

PRIMEIRO CLICK

[image: Primeiro click, tudo OK.]

SEGUNDO CLICK - Já incrementou

[image: SEGUNDO CLICK]

Seguem os códigos HTML e Javascript.

Vocês conseguem ajudar em uma solução??

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BOTÃO AMBIENTE//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-buscar-licencas-ambiente").click(function(){
    var urlapi = '';
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", urlapi, false);
    xhttp.send();
    var obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    var data_map = new Map();
    var index = 0;
      var objLength = obj.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
          if(data_map.has(obj[i].hostGroup.name)) {
            data_map.set(obj[i].hostGroup.name, data_map.get(obj[i].hostGroup.name) + +obj[i].consumedHostUnits);
            } 
          else {
                data_map.set(obj[i].hostGroup.name, +obj[i].consumedHostUnits);
            }
        }
    const objConverted = Object.fromEntries(data_map);      
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(objConverted); 
    data_map.forEach(montaTabelaLicencas);
    event.preventDefault();  
  });
});



function montaTabelaLicencas(licencasConsumidas, hostGroup) {

  var newRow = $('<tr class="linha-table">');
      var cols = "";

        cols += '<td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">' + hostGroup + '</td>';
        cols += '<td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">' + licencasConsumidas + '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

       $("#table-licencas").append(newRow); 
       return false; 
};   


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button-buscar-licencas-ambiente").click(function(){   
        let tdsValores = document.querySelectorAll('.quantidade')
        let total = 0 
            for (let i = 0; i < tdsValores.length; i++) {
                let valor = parseFloat(tdsValores[i].textContent)
                total = total + valor}
        document.getElementById("div-mostra-total-licencas").innerHTML = "Licenças Utilizadas: " + total;
    });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BOTÃO SERVIDOR//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button-buscar-licencas-servidor").click(function(){
    var urlapi = '';
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", urlapi, false);
    xhttp.send();
    var obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    var data_map = new Map();
    var index = 0;
      var objLength = obj.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < objLength; i++) {
          if(data_map.has(obj[i].displayName)) {
            data_map.set(obj[i].displayName, data_map.get(obj[i].displayName) + +obj[i].consumedHostUnits);
            } 
          else {
                data_map.set(obj[i].displayName, +obj[i].consumedHostUnits);
            }
        }
    const objConverted = Object.fromEntries(data_map);      
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(objConverted); 
    data_map.forEach(montaTabelaLicencas);
    event.preventDefault();  
  });
});



function montaTabelaLicencas(licencasConsumidas, displayName) {

  var newRow = $('<tr class="linha-table">');
      var cols = "";

        cols += '<td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">' + displayName + '</td>';
        cols += '<td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">' + licencasConsumidas + '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

       $("#table-licencas").append(newRow); 
       return false; 
};   


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button-buscar-licencas-servidor").click(function(){   
        let tdsValores = document.querySelectorAll('.quantidade')
        let total = 0 
            for (let i = 0; i < tdsValores.length; i++) {
                let valor = parseFloat(tdsValores[i].textContent)
                total = total + valor}
        document.getElementById("div-mostra-total-licencas").innerHTML = "Licenças Utilizadas: " + total;
    });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1400px) {
}
/*Propriedade do html*/
html {
    height: 100%;
}

/*Propriedade da div do header*/
header {
    height: 52px;
}
/*Propriedade customização do nav*/
.nav-custom {
    font-size: 15px;
}
/*Propriedade da imagem do logo no topo*/
#imagem-logo-dynatrace {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
/*Propriedade do body*/
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: BerninaSans, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#div-main{
    background-color: white;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;

    height: 90%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 90%;
}

#div-botoes-pesquisa{
    background-color: white;
    width: 29%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

#div-mostra-total-licencas{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#div-table-licencas{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}

.linha-titulo-tabela{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Inicio do html -->
<html lang="pt">
<!-- Inicio do head -->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="imagem/png" href="images/dynatrace.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- CSS Customizado -->
    <link href="css/ambiente-monitorado-3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- Fim do head -->
<!-- Inicio do body -->

<body>    
    <header>
        <title>Dynatrace Managed</title>
        <!-- Inicio do nav fixado no topo-->
        <div id="nav">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <!-- Inicio div container-fluid -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <!-- Imagem do logo da Dynatrace a esquerda -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="imagem-logo-dynatrace" src="images/dynatrace.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="Logo Principal" title="Logo Dynatrace"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Inicio ul nav com opções das páginas -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-custom">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="ambiente-monitorado.html">Ambientes Monitorados</a>
                        <li><a href="arquitetura.html">Arquitetura Dynatrace</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Downtime</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Indicadores</a></li>
                        <li><a href="como-funciona.html">Licenças</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Métricas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Fim ul nav com opções das páginas -->
                    <!-- Inicio ul nav da diretia, com search e login -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-custom">
                        <!-- Icone e botão login -->
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                        <!-- Inicio form do search -->
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <!-- Input do search -->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <!-- Botão de submit do search -->
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                        <!-- Icone do search -->
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Fim div input-group-btn -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fim div input-group -->
                        </form>
                        <!-- Fim form do search -->
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Fim ul nav da diretia, com search e login -->
                </div>
                <!-- Fim div container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Fim do nav fixado no topo-->
    </header>     
    <div id="div-main">
        <div id="div-botoes-pesquisa">
            <button class="button-title btn btn-info" id="button-buscar-licencas-ambiente" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"><i class="fas fa-bezier-curve fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="Por Ambiente"></i></button>
            <button class="button-title btn btn-info" id="button-buscar-licencas-servidor"><i class="fas fa-server fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="Por Servidor"></i></button><br><br>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" id="input-search-host-group" name="filtro" placeholder="Filtrar"> 
        </div>
        <div id="div-mostra-total-licencas"></div>
        <div id="div-table-licencas" class="div-table-licencas">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table-licencas">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="linha-titulo-tabela">Ambiente / Servidor</th>
                        <th class="linha-titulo-tabela">Host Units</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-body">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <script src="js/api-get-hosts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/disable-button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filtrar-search-licencas.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- Fim do body -->
</html>
<!-- Fim do html -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a montagem da tabela ficaria assim, já somando os valores. tirei as outras funcionalidades do evento apenas para demonstrar a parte da listagem :)

```js
$("#button-buscar-licencas-servidor").click(function(){

        //faz a requisição
        var urlapi = '';
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", urlapi, false);
        xhttp.send();
        var obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        
        //aqui passa o JSON como parâmetro
        montaTabelaLicencas(obj)
  });

function montaTabelaLicencas(obj) { 
    
    let rows = '';
    let total = 0;

    //percorre o JSON
    for(let item of obj){

        //soma o total
        total += parseFloat(item.licencasConsumidas);

        //para cada chave do JSON adiciona a linha em rows com os dados
        rows += `<tr class="linha-table"> 
                    <td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">${item.hostGroup}</td>
                    <td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">${item.licencasConsumidas}</td>
                </tr>` 
    }

    //adiciona o html do total
    $("#div-mostra-total-licencas").html("Licenças Utilizadas: " + total);

    //adiciona todas as <tr>
    $("#table-licencas").html(rows); 
    return false; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que entendi do seu problema, ao clicar mais de uma vez no botão seu código está somando o valor que ja existia, certo?

perceba que há dois eventos no elemento "#button-buscar-licencas-servidor", um deles é para fazer a requisição e outro para somar os valores. na função 'montaTabelaLicencas()' voce usa a função 'append()', use 'html()' pois assim você estará "substituindo" os elementos já existentes e seu segundo evento não percorrerá os elemento obsoletos novamente somando. Aconselho somar os valores logo ao percorrer o objeto para montar sua tabela, evitando assim outro loop e outra seleção de elementos. Use também apenas um evento '$(document).ready()', usando-o para chamar as funções necessárias. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: O problema é exatamente esse que citou, sempre que clico no botão, são incluidas linhas que já existiam.

Eu fiz essa alteração, mas não rolou.

Retorna agora somente a última linha

Comment: Uma outra coisa, os dois botão tem a função de mostrar a tabela com a partir de uma visão de sistemas e outroa uma visão por servidores.

Comment: use a função a seguir para montar sua tabela, passando o  objeto com os dados. assim você adicionará todas linhas sempre apenas uma vez.

function montaTabelaLicencas(obj) {

    let rows = ''
    for(let item of obj){

        rows += `
            <tr class="linha-table">
                <td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">${item.hostGroup}</td>
                <td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">${item.licencasConsumidas}</td>
            </tr>`
    }

    $("#table-licencas").html(rows); 
    return false; 
};

Comment: creio que o problema de seu código estar somando com o valor antigo seja realmente o fato de ele estar listando os dados novamente

Comment: Eu deixei da seguinte forma:

function montaTabelaLicencas(displayName,licencasConsumidas) { 
    let rows = ''; 
    for (let item of obj){ 
        rows += ` <tr class="linha-table"> <td class="hostgroup" id="hostgroup">${item.displayName}</td> <td class="quantidade" id="quantidade">${item.licencasConsumidas}</td> </tr>` 
    }    
    $("#table-licencas").html(rows); 
    return false; }; 

Mas retorna o erro abaixo:

api-get-hosts.js:84 Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Comment: ah sim, aí voce vai ter que organizar seu código pra passar o parâmetro certo, talvez, por exemplo, não vai precisar do "data_map" já que vai passar o objeto direto para a função. a mesma seria responsável por percorrer o JSON e pegar os dados necessários para criar a listagem como coloquei na variável "rows" em "item.licencasConsumidas" onde "item" é uma chave do JSON (obj) que é o retorno da API.